How can I prevent the mouse scroll wheel from continuing to scroll after release?
When scrolling with the mouse wheel on Ubuntu 22.04 with GNOME 42.9, if I scroll it a bit fast, the scrolling continues for approximately one second after releasing the wheel. This causes unintended zooming when pressing Ctrl.
How can I prevent the mouse scroll wheel from continuing to scroll after release?
Environment:

Ubuntu 22.04
GNOME 42.9


How fast is the system?  It's likely a result of the CPU/GPU not keeping up with the mouse wheel input.
